# How does the data.describe() method in pandas differentiate between population and sample data?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe, statistics

I have a question related to the data.describe() method in pandas. It gives you the relevant descriptive statistics of your dataset such as standard deviation. How does it tell if your data is from a population or a sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From pandas std doc:

```
Normalized by N-1 by default. This can be changed using the ddof argument
```

[reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.std.html#pandas.DataFrame.std)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the `.describe()` method gives you always the stats for your specific sample (drawn in the dataframe). It doesn't make inference about the population